# Why is a paragraph border affected by image placement?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have created a paragraph style called Note with a blue background and a border that normally looks like this example:

[image]

I would like to place an image to the right of the paragraph but when I try that the right border of the Note style paragraph is lost and a small white space appears on the left border as shown here:

[image]

Can I place the image and still preserve the right border in the paragraph style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is adjust the right indent on that note paragraph and place the image next to it with a Wrapping setting to be In Front or Behind the text.

[image]

Comment: Rich, That solution worked perfectly.